# wp_dropdown_pages auto submit

Tags: php, dropdown, select

What I have below currently works fine except for one issue: When a select item is chosen, it will correctly go to the subpage - however, if on a sub-page of the main site already, and a item is selected from the drop-down, the selection url is appended to the the existing page url, instead of passed as the full url. for example... if on site.com and choice1 is selected, we navigate to site.com/choice1/ - if we're on site.com/choice1 and choice2 is selected, it attempts to direct us to site.com/choice1/choice2 - I'm not sure how to adjust the code below to pass the full URL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
$select = wp_dropdown_pages(
    array(
        'post_type'         => 'ce_artists',
        'show_option_none'  => 'Select Artist',
        'echo'              => 0
    )
);
$select = preg_replace( "#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select );
echo $select;
?>
<noscript><input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" /></noscript>
```

Comment: You have written `this.form.submit()` Can you please mention what happens when the form is submitted and what is the `action` of the `form`? Better will be if you put the entire code having the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following piece of code.

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
    <?php
    $select = wp_dropdown_pages(
                        array(
                            'post_type' => 'ce_artists',
                            'show_option_none' => 'Select Artist',
                            'echo' => 0
                        )
                    );

    echo str_replace('<select ', '<select onchange="this.form.submit()" ', $select);
    ?>
</form>
```

You can find a similar example here in the **[codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages#Dropdown_with_Submit_Button)**